# Is there any way for Self-signed certificate for cordova?

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

We have an API which uses SSL but the certificate is not signed for now. Is there way to bypass the self-signed certificate?

[image]

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://xxxxx:50000/b1s/v1/Login",
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        data: jData,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        crossDomain: true,
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(xhr);
        },
        success: function (json) {
            alert("Success!");
        }
    });
```

I've created a simple asp.net MVC with that jQuery, it can login successfully.